# java string.replaceFirst/string.replaceLast regexp to remove all after second slash from end

Tags: java, regex

I've got some path like this /my/long/path/which/will/never/ends/.
I'd like to remove all after second slash from the end (so output will be something like /my/long/path/which/will/never/). How could I do that? I can use only javas String.replaceFirst or String.replaceAll.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
String str = "/my/long/path/which/will/never/ends/";
str = str.replaceFirst("[^/]+/$", "");
//=> /my/long/path/which/will/never/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aH8qG5/2)

Comment: `[^/]+` matches 1 or more of any non-slash character followed by a `/` and then end of input thus removing `ends/` or `any-thing-here/` from end of input.